# Get number of first time customers based on shipping date

Tags: database

I get the number of orders by shipping_arrival_date with the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as orders_on_day, shipping_arrival_dateenter preformatted text here 
  FROM sales_flat_order
group by shipping_arrival_date
order by shipping_arrival_date asc
```

How can I modify this query in a way that it shows me a third column with the number of first time customers on this particular shipping date?

I know that within sales_flat_order there is the `customer_id` which matches with the `entity_id` in `customer_entity`, but I somehow need to know if the customer has ordered before.

Does anybody can help here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SQL query I just tested which will get you orders for a certain date using the default order columns in Magento 1.9 (shipping_arrival is a custom column so I couldn't use it in this query).

```
SELECT SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM sales_flat_shipment as s
WHERE s.created_at LIKE '%2015-12-28%'
AND s.customer_id != ''
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales_flat_order as o WHERE o.customer_id = s.customer_id AND o.status = 'complete' having count(*) < 2)
```